# Change font size of tab titles in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, browser-tabs

I am browing a peculiar domain in Chrome. In doing so, my Google Chrome tabs have long names, and often the names don't fit in the space there is. So, I find myself repeatedly dragging my mouse to the tab, and hovering over it so it reveals its full name to me. This is really tideous because I need to do this several times.

Is there a way to tell Chrome to change the font size of the titles of it's tabs. If I make the font size small enough, most of the tab names will then be able to fit in the space.

Could you please tell me how to change Google Chrome's tab title font size?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the tab strip font size is not hard-coded. ( 
chrome/browser/views/tabs/tab_renderer.cc )

```
ResourceBundle& rb = ResourceBundle::GetSharedInstance();
title_font = new gfx::Font(rb.GetFont(ResourceBundle::BaseFont));
title_font_height = title_font->height();
```

BaseFont (height and font face) comes from the system UI font settings (MessageFont).

On Windows, it's possible to have too large a font for tab strips (whose other 
dimension do not change with the font size) if a user's machine is configured that 
way (e.g. low vision users).

Comment: I am on Linux. Is this a configuration that I as a user can change on the fly and make work without rebuilding Chrome locally?